# Magento 2 Autoprefixer in production mode

Tags: magento2, less, deploy, static-content-deploy, production-mode

Magento 2 comes with a preinstalled autoprefixer for Grunt.
But is it possible to use the autoprefixer in the production mode too?

I have a lot of CSS which does not work without the vendor prefixes in some browsers. I don't want declare a function for each property which has a vendor prefix, or add the prefix to each CSS class selector.

Comment: Sorry, donot understand your question.Can please explain what  is mean by `vendor prefixes`?

Comment: e.g.:
display: -webkit-box; 
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex; 
display: flex;

Comment: the functionality of https://autoprefixer.github.io/ for magento

Answer (score 0):

You can use .lib-css(transition, 0.3s ease , @_prefix: 1); for vendor prefixes. Use @_prefix: 1 to show cross browser compatibility code by default it is set to 0.